# Query to select attributes except specific fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, fields-attributes, query

What is the expression in ArcGIS to select values except for specific attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Fieldname <> attribute` is one way to query. If there are a list you can write a query that is something like `fieldname <> attribute1 AND fieldname <> attribute2`, or `fieldname NOT IN (attribute1, attribute2, attribute3)`.

This will return all values in a field that are not specified as an attribute.